# how to handle images in wysiwyg

Tags: image, wysiwyg

I am doing sort of a blog where i use ckeditor to edit the content. I want to upload a lot of images on each blog-post. Right now i'm saving the images as base64 string inside the content and then i just save the content of the blog-post in the database. This makes it suuuper slow. I realize this is far from the best way to do it but i just can't figure out how to save the images and open as i open the blog-post.

Please push me in the right direction!

I'm using azure and a virtual machine is pretty expensive. If the best alternative is to use a virtual machine and add the images to the virtual machine and then get them from there every time i open the post then i'll buy that. But i would rather use a solution where i don't need a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's no secret and in fact embedding the images as base64 is more complex than the standard solution of uploading the files to a server (I don't care which kind of server you want to use) and link them in the post